# Python3 unittest setup and teardown for the whole test suite

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

With python3 and the unnittest library is there a setup and teardown mechanism that applies to the full test run? I see one for module and class, but not a single run setup and teardown for the whole test suite.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create a parent class and put the test fixtures into it. Other tests class can inherit this parent class.

E.g.

`init_test.py`:

```py
import unittest


class InitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = {'id': '1'}

    def tearDown(self):
        self.user = None
```

`test_a.py`:

```py
from init_test import InitTest


class TestA(InitTest):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user, {'id': '1'})
```

`test_b.py`:

```py
from init_test import InitTest


class TestB(InitTest):
    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user, {'id': '1'})
```

`test_suites.py`:

```py
import unittest
from test_a import TestA
from test_b import TestB


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    test_classes = [TestA, TestB]

    suites = []
    for test_class in test_classes:
        suite = test_loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        suites.append(suite)

    big_suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(big_suite)
```

Unit test result:

```sh
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/54365191/init_test.py         6      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/54365191/test_a.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/54365191/test_b.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/54365191/test_suites.py      12      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          26      0   100%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54365191

Comment: Does your suggestion work with automatic test discovery?

Comment: Hello @month yes it works if you mean "loadTestsFromModule", you have only import your modules on the top of your runner.py, you modules have to have test classes inherited from TestCase, see example below, sorry for formatting


`import module1
import module2



loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite  = unittest.TestSuite()

suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(module1))
suite.addTest(loader.loadTestsFromModule(module2))

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=None, descriptions=True, verbosity=3)



result = runner.run(suite)`